# regex validate height without apostrophe

Tags: regex

I am needing to validate person's height to feet and inches without the use of single or double quotes.  Here is an example I am looking for:

- 508 ==> 5' 8"

Zero's are used as place holders in this requirement.  Additionally, I need to check for valid inches but must have placeholder:

- 08 ==> 8 inches valid
- 8  ==> 8 inches invalid (missing placeholder)
- 13 ==> invalid (11 is max)

Feet and inches together:

- 511 ==> 5'11" (valid)
- 512 ==> 5'12" (invalid, should be written as 600)
- 513 ==> 5'13" (invalid, should be written as 601)

I have tried the following:

- ^(\d{1,5})((\s?)(-?)(\s?)([0-9]|(1[0-1])))?$

but this does not check for placeholder neither does it handle numbers greater than 12.

Appreciate any help in resolving this!

Comment: "Neither does it handle numbers greater than 12." Are numbers greater than 12 valid or not? If they aren't valid, then you don't want the regex to match them. If they are, then you do. Your regex doesn't match numbers greater than 12, which seems right.

Comment: Correct, 513 would not match the requirement, neither would 512. I should have caught that when I elicited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]*((0[0-9])|(1[01]))$
```

It means:

- `[0-9]*` 0 or more 0-9 characters

  - `0[0-9]` followed by 00 to 09
  - `1[01]` OR 10 to 11

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/hSf577/3)

Comment: that works! Thanks much!  I always get a little confused with regex.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^\d{0,1}0[1-9]|1[0-2]$
```